# Eclipse doesn't put XML files in project's own buildpath

Tags: xml, eclipse, classpath

I created a standard Java Project in Eclipse, placed a XML file in the `src` folder with the intent to grab it by `Class#getResourceAsStream()`, and I was baffled when Eclipse can't seem to locate the XML file in the classpath. After a little test it turns out that files with other extensions are perfectly located.

Here's a screen which says it all:

[image]

It prints `null` for the `/test.xml` resource. The `Class#getResourceAsStream()` obviously doesn't make any difference.

I checked the project's `/bin` folder and the XML file is indeed not there. I've checked all settings to see if there isn't some filter to exclude certain files from ending up in the `/bin` folder during the build, but all in vain.

How is this caused and how can I solve it? I'm using Eclipse Galileo with build id 20090920-1017.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you put the xml in a subfolder such as resources?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds vaguely familiar. Go to Prefs -> Java -> Compiler -> Building -> Output Folder, and make sure the "filtered resources" field doesn't include XML files.  Also check the project-specific preferences.

I seem to recall that older versions of Eclipse had this in by default, but I'm not sure why it'd happen with a newer version.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! As to the version, I guess that it must be caused because I always exported/imported the preferences in flavor of `epf` file when upgrading Eclipse.